# Maven profile removing dependency

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I have pom with declared dependencies A,B and C. Is it possible to create a profile which removes dependencies, so that when I compile with that profile, I end up for example with compiled dependency A and B (without C)?

Comment: Your question is about `<dependencies>` section, right?

Comment: Andrew Logvinov - Righ, dependencies A,B,C are declared in <dependencies/> section, I want to remove dependency C using profile. Is that possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do not know a way to exclude top level dependencies inside a profile (`<exlusions>` is only available for transitive dependencies). But you can specify your 'normal' dependencies in a default profile and your reduced dependencies in a seperate profile as for example:

```
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.14</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>excludeDependency</id>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

Compiling with the 'excludeDependency' profile will fail if you use log4j somewhere.

Your use case is not clear. Maybe some other solutions like [optional dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) or [provided dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) will also fit your needs. Have a look at these possibilities.

Comment: That would be the best solution, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

In Maven the profile are additive to the base profile so I have found this pattern of usage good for excluding dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Exclude</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.14</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then you "exclude" the dependency by changing the scope to test. Doesn't suit all usages, but just as another option.